# Unexpected results while marshaling list of struct

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling

**I could not find out what I'm doing wrong. I think I'm doing everything by the numbers, but it looks like I'm missing something.**

On the managed side:

```
public override List<TimerPair> GetNativeTimers()
{
    var listPtr = HgrDll.GetNativeTimers(out var size, out var ptrShift);

    if (listPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new NullReferenceException("sounds like the list"
             + " pointer was not given");

    var timerPairList = new List<TimerPair>(size);
    var structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TimerPairStruct2));

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        var o = Marshal.PtrToStructure<TimerPairStruct2>(listPtr).ToTimerPair();
        timerPairList.Add(o);
        listPtr += structSize;
    }
    return timerPairList;
}
```

The target struct (used for intermediate compute) and class:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
internal struct TimerPairStruct2 : ITimerPairStruct
{
    public long Time;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=64)]
    public string Descr;

    public TimerPair ToTimerPair() => new TimerPair(Descr, Time);
}

public class TimerPair
{
    public string Descr { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public TimerPair(string descr, long time)
    {
        Descr = descr;
        Time = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0, (int)((double)time/1000000));
    }
}
```

For the Pinvoke part:

```
[DllImport("DwarfHomograph.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetNativeTimers(out int size, out int ptrShift);
```

and now on the native side:

```
DwarfHgr* DwarfAsset = nullptr;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) list<TimerPair>* GetNativeTimers(
    int* size,
    int* ptrShift)
{
    return DwarfAsset->GetNativeTimers(size, ptrShift);
}
```

the used method from the `DwarfHgr` class:

```
list<TimerPair>* DwarfHgr::GetNativeTimers(int* size, int* ptrShift)
{
    TimerPairsList = Sw.AsTimerPairs();
    *size = static_cast<int>(TimerPairsList.size());
    *ptrShift = sizeof(TimerPair);
    return &TimerPairsList;
}
```

and the member is `list<TimerPair> TimerPairsList;`

The struct I'm marshaling is:

```
//#pragma pack(push,8)
struct __declspec(dllexport) TimerPair final
{
    long long Time{}; // ns
    char Descr[64]{};
};
//#pragma pack(pop)
```

---

I'm having unit tests in both native and managed sides; the **expected result** looks like (native):

```
ImageA processing: 22.0704ms
ImageB processing: 22.0448ms
MatFullA.copyTo: 1.87452ms
MatToSparse: 1.93482ms
calcOpticalFlowFarneback: 1115.48ms
create flowSparse image: 10.1416ms
```

But I have this (managed):

```
°óŠqÉ: 1,964,675.000000ms
q$Fý: 140,725,780.000000ms
xr$Fý: 140,725,780.000000ms
: 549,755.000000ms
à¡CUÉ: 1,964,675.000000ms
: 0.000000ms
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Last 2 points: I don't get what I expect.

Comment: Don't try marshalling C++ types such as `std::list` through simple p/invoke. You will end in a world of hurt, as you already experienced. Either, convert your std::list into a plain C-type array before marshalling it , write a wrapper class in C++/CLI which calls the native DLL functions and translates the C++ data types into the managed data types you need/want (possibly with the help of something like https://github.com/goldshtn/marshalfx; but i have never used that code myself, so i cannot give any opinion about its usefulness/stability/features/etc...)